# Using Regex in Python to capture any number(s) with a leading $, a trailing %, or any number with a decimal, a comma or space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a script that matches all numbers, including any number(s) with a leading $ (e.g. $12), a trailing % (e.g. 12%), a decimal inside (e.g. 1.24550), or a comma inside (e.g. 1,250,000), or a space in between (e.g $12,500 1234)

When I try to put this all together into one line, I can't get it to work correctly. One issue was that it kept grabbing letters/words and unnecessary white space. I tried experimenting, unsuccessfully, with different anchors as a way of resolving the letters/white space issue. I came up with this:

```
^\$?\.?\d+\.?\,?\d+\.?\,?\%?\s?\d+$
```

This works for most input, however, it won't work with input like:

```
asbdf 12234
```

It just skips the numbers altogether. If I remove the anchors, then it will match the numbers, but will also grab a bunch of white space so I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Regex pattern:

```
\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?
```

- `\$?` zero or one `?`
- `(?:\d[ ,.]?)+` matches one or more of a digit followed by zero or one of space, comma, point
- `%?` matches zero or one `%`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fwzIXD/3)

---

**Edit:**

Getting only *words*:

```
(?:^|\s)(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)
```

Now, you can get the captured group 1 (only one here) e.g. with `re.search`:

```
In [10]: re.search(r'(?:^|\s)(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)', 'abcd $123%').group(1)
Out[10]: '$123%'


In [11]: re.search(r'(?:^|\s)(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)(?=\s|$)', 'www.learninghowtobuild101.com/greattipspart2').group(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b9a600842ec9> in <module>()
----> 1 re.search(r'(?:^|\s)(\$?(?:\d[ ,.]?)+%?)', r'www.learninghowtobuild101.com/greattipspart2').group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: This is really good, much appreciated. The only issue I'm running into is it's pulling numbers from things like URLs (which I want to avoid). For instance, if I test it on **www.learninghowtobuild101.com/greattipspart2** it will pull all of those numbers too (i.e. 101 and 2). Is there a way around this? I tried working on some alternatives, but kept running into issues.

Comment: Thanks again, is there a way to do this without grouping? I feel like there has to be a simple, straightforward way of pulling all of these numbers in without any words, I'm just not great at regex so I'm probably missing something. But yeah I'd like to just grab everything in 1 group if possible. Just not sure if this is actually an option or not.

Comment: @David Grouping is needed as the `re` module does not support variable width lookbehind, look at `regex` module if you want that. Also, what's wrong with grouping?

Comment: nothing wrong with grouping, I'm just trying to get better with regex and thought there might be something more straightforward for grabbing all of these different numbers that I may have overlooked. I have a feeling I was way over-complicating things

Answer (score 1):

Drop the anchors and use `.search()` instead of `.match()`

```
>>> import re
>>> my_number_finder = re.compile(r"""\$?\.?\d+\.?\,?\d+\.?\,?\%?\s?\d+""")
>>> m = my_number_finder.search("asbdf 12234")
>>> m.group()
'12234'
>>> m = my_number_finder.search("asbdf $12234")
>>> m.group()
'$12234'
>>> m = my_number_finder.search("asbdf 122.34%")
>>> m.group()
'122.34'
>>> m = my_number_finder.search("asbdf 3,122.34%")
>>> m.group()
'3,122.34'
>>> m = my_number_finder.search("asbdf 3,122 112")
>>> m.group()
'3,122 112'
```

I can't explain the inconsistent treatment of `$` and `%` (because I haven't looked hard enough) but that behaviour was already present in your regex.